# simplexml_load_file wait for response

Tags: php

I have a script where I'm pinging off to Google's geocoding API to obtain a lat / lng.  Occasionally, however, the script attempts to execute further actions before the response has been received.

The code I have is:

```
function getvalues($myzip) {
    $hello =  simplexml_load_file('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address='.$myzip.'&sensor=true');
    return $hello;
}
```

How would I go about having it pause and not execute the next functions until google has replied with the relevant data?  I tried doing a while loop - but that was clumsy and caused other problems.

edit to add:

My next bit of code is:

```
$mything = getvalues($myzip);
$lat = ($mything->result[0]->geometry[0]->location[0]->lat);
$lng = ($mything->result[0]->geometry[0]->location[0]->lng);
```

and when showing errors - I see -

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /calc_dist3.php on line 14

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /calc_dist3.php on line 14

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /calc_dist3.php on line 14

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /calc_dist3.php on line 15

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /calc_dist3.php on line 15

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /calc_dist3.php on line 15

(with $lat and $lng being defined on lines 14/15 respectively)

Comment: So when you call `getvalues()` ... lines AFTER it in your php are executing before the function returns anything ??? Are you sure that `simplexml_load_file` didnt bail? Do some error check and output, to make sure.

Comment: Execution CANNOT and WILL NOT continue here until simplexml_load_file returns... so either it's a timeout or connection problem.

Comment: Yep - connection problem at the server.  Thanks!

Comment: @user7355700 I'm sure Google limits the number of requests per second per host... look at my answer below for a possible solution. Also, you could cache a number of frequently accessed zips... or store them in your DB and check there first before pinging google.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is mainly a [sequential](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/144481/what-is-sequential-code-execution/144483) programming language. Meaning each line must be executed fully before continuing to the next line. One way to help you see this is if you put the variable holding the function result into an if statement like so:

```
if($mything = getvalues($myzip))
{
    $lat = ($mything->result[0]->geometry[0]->location[0]->lat);
    $lng = ($mything->result[0]->geometry[0]->location[0]->lng);
}
```

This ensures that the $lat and $lng variables will only run once a value is return from the function.

Secondly, it may just be a case that the Google API doesn't have a lat or lng for the zip code. Wrap the variable initialisation inside [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) if statements, and for debugging, display the API result on error.

```
if($mything = getvalues($myzip))
{
    if(isset($mything->result[0]->geometry[0]->location[0]->lat))
    {
        $lat = ($mything->result[0]->geometry[0]->location[0]->lat);
    }
    else
    {
        // display error
        echo "<pre>",print_r($mything),"</pre>";
    }

    if(isset($mything->result[0]->geometry[0]->location[0]->lng))
    {
        $lng = ($mything->result[0]->geometry[0]->location[0]->lng);
    }
    else
    {
        // display error
        echo "<pre>",print_r($mything),"</pre>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<pre>",print_r("Google API failed"),"</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Execution CANNOT continue until the simplexml_load_file returns (it returns false on failure). Perhaps it was a timeout issue with google server... or maybe simplexml_load_file has an internal timeout... either way, you should be able to check again until you are able to retrieve the data or reach an arbitrary timeout period.

```
function getValues(int $zip, int $timeout_secs = 2){
    $hello = null;
    $timeout = time() + $timeout_secs;
    while(time() < $timeout && empty($hello)){
        $hello = simplexml_load_file('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address='.$zip.'&sensor=true');
    }
    return($hello);
}

if($arr = getValues(95014)){
    print_r($arr);
    echo '<br>';
}else{
    echo 'Failed to open XML file<br>';
}
```

The second parameter expects a timeout interval in seconds. This represents the amount of time allowed to retrieve the data before PHP gives up and returns false, signifying that there was an error.

Further: you can change from a timeout period to an arbitrary number of attempts... might work better.